# sending an AJAX request for an audio blob to an async API

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working on a legacy system and I'm trying to call an HTTP handler which I have added some logic which retrieves audio blob from an Azure service.
The thing is, I can't seem to get the content back to the client so I can play it.
The response that I get from a jQuery call is:
"System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"

This is the processRequest code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var text = "walk";
        Authentication auth = new Authentication("subscriptionID");
        context.Response.Write(auth.getVoice(text));
    }
```

Here's the getVoice function:

```
 public async Task<string> getVoice(string text)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                    .Add("User-Agent", "uagent");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.token);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("host", "westeurope.tts.speech.microsoft.com");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-MICROSOFT-OutputFormat", "audio-16khz-32kbitrate-mono-mp3");
                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(VoiceUri);
                // send xml post 
                var voiceTest = "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Female'\n\rname='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, ZiraRUS)'>\n\rWalk\n\r</voice></speak>";
                var data = new StringContent(voiceTest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                data.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/ssml+xml");
                var result = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, data);
                return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
```

The server API call is successful but I can't seem to receive it on the client side in order to play it to the user afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unwrap the result of `auth.getVoice`. You can do it by using `await` key word. Also you need you handler to implement `HttpTaskAsyncHandler` class in order to make it work

```
public class TestHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
{
    public async override Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var text = "walk";
        Authentication auth = new Authentication("subscriptionID");
        context.Response.Write(await auth.getVoice(text)); //added await here
    }
//..
}
```

Comment: Ok, the code change allowed me to receive the blob data but I still don't know how to play it.
I'm trying to use the audio element but with no success so far.